# How can I have the same height for the color bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot some data, however the color bar is higher than the plot. How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Generate data:
x = np.linspace(1, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(1,100, 10)

for i in range(10, 100, 10):
    x = append(x, np.linspace(i, i, 10))
    y = append(y, np.linspace(1, 100, 10))

z = numpy.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=100)

# Set up a regular grid of interpolation points
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# Interpolate
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

s = ax.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.xlim([0,200])

#s = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, marker = 's')
plt.colorbar(mappable=s, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: use the `shrink=` option for the colorbar.  like this:
`plt.colorbar(mappable=s, ax=ax, shrink=0.7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution (for your example) is to remove the line

```
plt.xlim([0,200])
```

But since you've put it there, I assume that you *really* want/need it there. So then, you have to manually adapt the height of the colorbar:

```
cb = plt.colorbar(mappable=s, ax=ax)
plt.draw()
posax =  ax.get_position()
poscb = cb.ax.get_position()
cb.ax.set_position([poscb.x0, posax.y0, poscb.width, posax.height])
```

Using the `shrink` argument of `colorbar` as @MaxNoe suggests might also do the trick. But you will have to fiddle around to get the right value.